# Multiple USB Storage Devices on Honeycomb

Tags: usb, 3.0-honeycomb

I just got an Acer A500 tablet, which has a full size USB port and supports FAT32 USB storage devices.  What I would like to do though, is hook up a hub and connect multiple, so use the tablet as a way to copy photos from an SD card reader to an external USB hard drive for backup during a trip.

I poked around and found that when I have two devices plugged in you can actually see the device entries listed under /dev/usb although only one of them (usually whatever was plugged in first) will actually show up under /mnt/usb_storage (apparently the default).

Anyone know of a way to get it to make both usable? 
I'm guess I'll have to root it so I can run the mount command? (Unfortunately, no one has figured that out yet that I know of.)

Comment: I think that tablet has now been rooted (see xda-developers) so you should be able to issue mount command manually, or write an apk that does so.

Comment: Do you want an answer to the general question, or to your specific setup?  For example, the Asus transformer has multiple USB host ports so the use of the hub is not needed there.

Comment: I know on the Galaxy that the USB did not have enough power to power USB ext. HDD. Have you tried a powered USB HUB?

Answer (score 1):

The critical failure seems to be the use of a USB hub.  On my transformer I can mount two different thumb drives and an SD card at the same time.

[image: photos or you're lieing!]

The left port us USBDrive2, even when only one thumb drive is plugged in.  So it appears to me that it is a honeycomb thing mapping each port to a specific directory, ignoring the possiblity of USB hubs.  Unfortunately I no longer have a USB hub to test this theory on since my wife has watched one too many hoarders shows.

The A500 only has one USB host, but it also has a MicroSD reader in additon.  So an alternative solution you may want to consider is using a micro SD card in your camera in a SD adapter and then popping that into the A500.  A microSD card is quite a bit cheaper than a Transformer + dock.